# Java - openCV - Area Selection on live camera feed

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to do a area selection to create a mask on the camera view provided by **CameraBridgeViewBase**. Is it possible? If yes how ? I tried to look in this forum and over the **opencv.answers's** forum site but there is no question of this type. If anybody can please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the opencv forum, here is the link if can help some one: http://answers.opencv.org/question/55734/opencv-area-selection-on-live-camera-feed/.